# Compare Firestore timestamp with NodeJS timestamp in google cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to compare timestamp to trigger a if statement in my cloud function.

```
    const orderRef = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('orders')
    .doc(orderId)
    .get();

    const createdAt = orderRef.data()!.createdAt.toDate();
    const currentTime = new Date();
    
    // Calculate difference
    const diff = currentTime.getTime() - createdAt; 
    
    //convert difference to minutes
    const diffInMinutes = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
    console.log('Diff in minutes: ' + diffInMinutes);
    
    // Main Logic
    if (diffInMinutes <= 10) {
      //Logic
    }
```

Right now, I am getting error that is toDate is not a function and as per my understanding that is due to serialisation of data. Kindly help with how can I convert it back to object.

Comment: We're missing some necessary context here. How is your `orderRef` initialized and where/how do you run this code?

Comment: You can add a type check as follows to solve this issue : `if (createdAt instanceof admin.firestore.Timestamp) { createdAtDate = createdAt.toDate(); }` Assuming you have initialized the admin SDK with admin. Do comment back if it worked or not.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I have upated the code.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like your `createdAt` field is not a [`Timestamp` object](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html), which is where `toDate()` is defined. It's hard to say why that is without seeing the [complete (yet still minimal) context of how anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: @Rishabh can you also provide `console.log(orderRef.data())` ?

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If so then acknowledge it if not then we can solve further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Frank van Puffelen mentioned above. It is possible that your `createdAt` field is not a `Timestamp` at all.  For that you can add a if clause to check as follows :

```js
import {
    Timestamp
} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const orderRef = await firestore.collection("orders").doc(orderId).get();
const docData = orderRef.data();
console.log(docData);
if (docData?.createdAt instanceof Timestamp) {
    const createdAtDate = docData?.createdAt.toMillis(); // Returns the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch
    const currentTime = new Date();

    // Calculate difference
    const diff = currentTime.getTime() - createdAtDate;

    // Convert difference to minutes
    const diffInMinutes = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
    console.log("Diff in minutes: " + diffInMinutes);

    // Main Logic
    if (diffInMinutes <= 10) {
        console.log("Difference is less than 10: " + diffInMinutes);
    } else {
        console.log("Difference is more than 10: " + diffInMinutes);
    }
} else {
    console.log(docData?.createdAt, " is not a Timestamp");
}
```

Instead of converting Timestamp to Date and then Time you can directly convert Timestamp to a numeric value with [**toMillis()**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#tomillis) method

Reference :

- [**Timestamp**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Resulted datetime formats of both variables are different.

createdAt is converting with ".toDate()"

currentTime.getTime()

these 2 functions will generate output in different formats.due to that it is not possible to get the difference simply var1-var2.

first convert both in same format then it will work.

Comment: Can you help with a sample code. As toDate() method does not exists.

Comment: use getTime() function in both places.